# how to pass data data from collection view cell to view controller

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionviewcell, swift4.2

I have a button in collectionview cell and i am trying to access the current title from the view controller.

But when I try to access, I get the title as the default title "Button"

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
             let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "graphCell", for: indexPath) as! graphCell


             let row = indexPath.row

            if row == 0{
                print("Compare")
            }

            else if row == 1{
                let optSelected=cell.chooseBTN.title(for: .normal)
                print(option)
                if optSelected=="Sales"{
                    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

                    let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SalesVC") as! SalesVC

                    vc.buttonClicked = "Sales"; navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
                }
                else if optSelected=="Collection"{
                    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

                    let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SalesVC") as! SalesVC

                    vc.buttonClicked = "Collection"; navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)

                }

            }

            else if row == 2{
                print("PRO-wise")
            }
            else if row == 3{
                print("TAT")
            }

        }
```

Comment: Don't call `dequeueReusableCell()` elsewhere that's not `collectionView(_:cellForRowAt:)`. You might want to use let cell = `collectionView.cell(forRowAt:indexPath)` (or something like that). But you could also, and that's better retrieve the value from your dataSource/array that help you construct the cell.

Comment: You should not use dequeueReusableCell() or cellForRow in order to get the title. I suggest you to use row Index for retrieving the title from the array/List or any data source that you have. Or if it has a complex logic for retrieving the title, use another array for saving titles when presenting cells and then use rowIndex and that array for retrieving the title

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace

```
 let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "graphCell", for: indexPath) as! graphCell
```

with

```
 let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at:indexPath) as! graphCell
```

---

also this

```
let optSelected=cell.chooseBTN.title(for: .normal)
print(option)
if optSelected=="Sales"{
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

    let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SalesVC") as! SalesVC

    vc.buttonClicked = "Sales"; navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
}
else if optSelected=="Collection"{
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

    let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SalesVC") as! SalesVC

    vc.buttonClicked = "Collection"; navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
}
```

can be replaced with

```
  let vc =  storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SalesVC") as! SalesVC
  vc.buttonClicked = cell.chooseBTN.title(for: .normal)
  navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
```